# Linq aggregate with strings only returns one item instead of two

Tags: c#, linq

Although I have 2 items in the w.RefrigeratorDetails collection, the aggregated string only shows only data about the second item, not the first.

Why is that?

```
RefrigeratorDetails = w.RefrigeratorDetails
                        .Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index + 1 })
                        .Aggregate(string.Empty,
                                   (current, item) =>
                                        "test1" + item.Index + ": " + item.Value.SerialNumber + Environment.NewLine
                                        + "test2" + item.Index + ": " + item.Value.ArticleNumber + Environment.NewLine
                                        + "test3" + item.Index + ": " + (item.Value.DateOfPurchase.HasValue
                                                                         ? item.Value.DateOfPurchase.Value.ToShortDateString()
                                                                         : "")
                                        + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine)
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: You are not using `current` in your aggregate. Probably want to concatenate with that.

Comment: Servy answered it for you - but really this is just another "help me debug my code" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you're aggregating your data you're ignoring `current`, and projecting each additional record into an item containing only that records data without incorporating the previous data.

Comment: Yes. The aggregator needs to be (current, item) => current + <Insert concatenation fest here>